# Workaround for 3rd party library that doesn't support SSL

Tags: javascript, ssl

I'm currently trying to use a 3rd party library, tested the code on a development environment which worked perfectly. However, upon uploading the finished item and testing over SSL I've found that the 3rd party library isn't available on a CDN or over SSL. As a result my browser blocks the javascript file as it's not over SSL.

In these circumstances, I'd usually just copy the javascript to be hosted locally which would get around the issue. The problem with this is that the javascript's link is actually a .aspx file and the content seems to be generated dynamically. When I attempted to use the file locally it was stating that some variables don't exist.

My question is, would a simple PHP wget/CURL for the file be sufficient to get the dynamic javascript file ( I would assume not as this would be similar to hosting the file myself ) or is there a simpler work around for such libraries?

The library file is: http://www.worldwidetelescope.org/scripts/wwtsdk.aspx which is a microsoft library

Comment: what's the library? have you contacted the owners/documentation for any official options?

Comment: You could host a proxy on an SSL-enabled server, which forwards requests to the third party server.

Comment: @atmd I've updated my post. Unfortunately, it's a microsoft library and there are no contact details

Comment: @joews thank you for the comment. I'll have a look into that it's a good idea.

Comment: Make sure that you only proxy whitelisted URLs - [running an open redirect is a bad idea](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect)